# Find comments And blank lines in source using Visual Studio 2008 "Find And Replace" with regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, replace

My question is simple, I want to find all commented and blank lines in my source code and delete them. I've tried `^(REM [\d\D]*?[\r\n])|(?<SL>\'[\d\D]*?[\r\n])$` but it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VS2008 supports zero-width lookaheads:

- Find: `(?:\r\n[\t ]*`[symbol_initiating_full_line_comment]`[^\r\n]*|\r\n[\t ]*)+(?=\r\n)`
- Replace: null

If VS2008 does not support zero-width lookaheads:

- Find: `(?:\r\n[\t ]*`[symbol_initiating_full_line_comment]`[^\r\n]*|\r\n[\t ]*)+(\r\n)`
- Replace: `$1`

Answer assumes `$1` is how VS2008 represents the first unnnamed group, some applications use `\1`.

Further information: `*?` is redundant, as `*` matches 0 or more, and `?` makes the previous symbol optional.

Comment: Works great if I'm using a third party addin which supports normal regex. But doesn't work with Visual Studio 2008 find and replace regex.